# Is it possible to update one column always and another conditionally in one single statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with two columns `a` and `b`. There is also a `id` column, which is the primary key. I now want to update a row in my table as following:

- Column `a` must always be updated.
- Column `b` must be updated if the current value is equal to a certain provided value.

Is it possible to do such update in one single `UPDATE` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CASE`:

```
UPDATE tab
SET a = val
   ,b = CASE WHEN b = provided_value THEN new_value ELSE b END
WHERE ...;
```

Technically speaking `b` always be updated but it will be identity change from `b` -> `b`

Comment: Interesting. Thank you! Is there overhead (in PostgreSQL) when doing a dummy update, such as `b = b`?

Comment: @forever-living I would say it depends. If you really want to skip second column update you need to use dynamic -SQL or wrap everything with `IF ELSE control structure` and provide 2 seprate update statements.

Comment: @forever-living You're already updating the row due to setting `a`, which means a new record is being written, so I think any overhead in setting the second field unnecessarily at times would be minimal.

Comment: Makes sense! Thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply `case` condition

```
update table1 set
    a = updatevala,
    b = (case when bcondition then updatevalb else b end)
```